# Promeblemas con jquery y ajax keyup y preventdefault

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas, he estado tratando de solucinar un problema desde hace algunos días, sucede que el error me lo marca en una línea de código la cuál únicamente contiene el e.preventDefault(); pero ese bloque de código si se ejecuta, donde truena es al hacer click para que realize la acción posterior a este(que sería la linea 190), pero la información que he encontrado no me ha sido útil, el error es el siguiente:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined
   <anonymous> js/function.js:131
   jQuery 12
   <anonymous> js/function.js:197
   jQuery 9
   <anonymous> js/function.js:190
```

Y ya revisé cada nombre de cada id y están correctamente escritos.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$('#txt_cod_producto').keyup(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //linea 131
        var prod= $(this).val();
        var action= 'infoprod';

        if(prod != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                async : true,
                data: {action:action,prod:prod},
    
                success: function(response){
                    //console.log(response);
                    if(response != 'error'){
                        var info= JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#txt_descripcion').html(info.descripcion);
                        $('#txt_existencia').html(info.existencia);
                        $('#txt_precio').html(info.precio);
                        $('#txt_cantidad_producto').val(1);
                        $('#txt_cantidad_producto').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $('#add_producto_venta').slideDown();
                    }   
                    else{
                        $('#txt_descripcion').html('-');
                        $('#txt_existencia').html('-');
                        $('#txt_precio').html('0.00');
                        $('#txt_precio_total').html('0.00');
                        $('#txt_cantidad_producto').val('0.00');

                        $('#txt_cantidad_producto').attr('disabled','disaled');
                        $('#add_producto_venta').slideUp();
                    } 
                },

                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
        
    });

$('.addp').click(function(e){ //linea 190
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var codproducto = $('#txt_cod_producto');
        var cantidad = $('#txt_cantidad_producto');
        var action = 'addProductoDetalle';

        $.ajax({ //linea 197
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async : true,
            data: {act:action,prod:codproducto,cant:cantidad},

            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },

            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

El ajax.php solo esta capturando lo que fuene de funciton.js, tiene los siguiente:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'addProductoDetalle'){
            print_r($_POST);
            exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el evento `keyUp`.

Como ya sabes existen 3 eventos de tecla: `keyDown`, `keyPress` y `keyUp`.

Cada vez que pulses una tecla, se disparan estos 3 eventos, en este orden.

- `KeyDown` se dispara cuando la tecla acaba de ser pulsada.
- `KeyPres` se dispara mientras lo esta.
- `KeyUp` se dispara cuando se suelta la tecla.

Por lo tanto, con esta explicacion, entendemos que no podermos hacer un `preventDefault()` de este evento.

Cambialo por `keyDown`.

Comment: Que tal Srsole, te comento que hice lo que me indicas pero sigue sin funcionar, incuso al colocar el KeyDown no me permite escribir en el input.

Comment: intenta poniendo  e = this; justo antes de e.preventDefault(); //linea 131

Comment: @Oscar_GT entiendo, que el error no sigue siendo "e is undefined",nos dices cual es?